# how to edit lines in list asynchronously in python all at once

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

have this list of passwords about 800k and want to run on each item "password" in the list then add "123" to the end of the password how do I do that all at once or at least faster
going through the 800k in a for loop will take a while I tried threading but it did not do any change on time

Comment: It shouldn't take a lot of time with for loop or list comprehension either. 800k samples took <1 second on Google Colab for me

Comment: I built a list of 800,000 strings each of 8 characters in length. Then timed the duration for appending '123' to each string in the list. It took 0.07s. Multithreading is slower because this is CPU-bound and not well-suited to that technique. Normally one would use multiprocessing for CPU-bound activities but in this trivial use-case the overheads of multiprocess management would also be slower compared to inline processing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is a good performance for your case

but to make it in threading , you can do like this:

```
import threading

list_of_your_password = ['a', 'b']

new_pass = []

def add_char(list_of_your_password, i):
            
    new_pass.append(list_of_your_password[i] + '123')

for i, password in enumerate(list_of_your_password):    
    x = threading.Thread(target=add_char, args=(list_of_your_password, i))
    x.start()

print (new_pass)
```